# Laravel - Routes: Controller nested controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-controller

My routes:

```php
Route::apiResource('courses', 'CourseController');
Route::apiResource('courses.classrooms', 'ClassroomController');
```

List: `php artisan route:list`

```
api/v1/courses/{course}
api/v1/courses/{course}/classrooms/{classroom}
```

My question is: all my functions in `classroom controller` needs the `course`, something like that

```php
public function index($course_id)
{
  $classroom = Classroom::where('course_id', $course_id)->get();
  return $classroom;
}

public function store($course_id, Request $request)
{
// ...
  $classroom->course_id = $course_id;
// ...
}

public function show($course_id, $id)
{
  $classroom = Classroom::where('course_id', $course_id)->find($id);
  return $classroom;
}
// ...
```

Have some Policy/Helper in Laravel to accomplish this automatically?

I believe it's not necessary to add the property `$course_id` in all functions manually, what can I do?

Comment: Look for PROVIDERS in Laravel.

Comment: What about registering the classrom controller with: `Route::apiResource('courses/{course}/classrooms', 'ClassroomController');

Comment: @mdexp my route isn’t a problem it’s happen, my problem is need to add ``$course_id`` in all functions in my classroom controller

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `group` to enclose all your routes. Something like:

```
 Route::group(['prefix' => '{course}'], function () {

// you can place your routes here

});
```

So all the routes that exist in that group will already have the `course` value in the url path and you don't have to "rewrite it" for every route.

If that field is set by you for example an `env` variable then inside your `RouteServiceProvider` you can put the prefix you want in the  `mapApiRoutes` function.

```
 protected function mapApiRoutes()
    {
        Route::prefix('/api/v1/courses/'.config('app.myVariable'))
             ->middleware('api')
             ->namespace($this->namespace)
             ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
    }
```

That way ALL your api endpoints will start with that prefix and you can have it in all the endpoints.

Comment: My routes make it automatically, the problem is because I need to get the property in all function of my classroom controller and I want an alternative [ policy / providers ] to get the course automatically.

Comment: Where is that course coming from? How you set it? Is it coming from the user like a request or is it environment based ? If it is coming as a request to group all your endpoints will solve your issue and you can access it like `$request->course`. If it is a field in your env file then i would follow the second approach.

Comment: When I put ``Route::apiResource('courses.classrooms', 'ClassroomController');`` Laravel make automatically ``api/v1/courses/{course}/classrooms/{classroom}``, that is to get my "classroom" need be related to course

Answer (score 0):

If the routes are registered correctly like you posted, your methods in the `ClassroomsController` should receive an additional parameter that's the course id fragment from the url.

For example if you request `/api/v1/courses/1/classrooms` route, the controller will receive the correct `{course}` parameter set to `1` as the first parameter.

You could then implement the index method of the ClassroomsController to use implicit model binding and get the Course instance with the given url id for the course.

To do so you have to type-hint the Course model for the first function's parameter and name the variable as the url fragment you want to use to retrive your model.

In your code example, you should do:

```php
public function index(Course $course)
{
    return $course->classrooms;
}
```

**Note:** I assume you have a relationship between Course and Classroom models to retrive the classrooms from the course model instance

You can read more about that on the official documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#implicit-binding)

Comment: It’s working, but don’t solve my problem... I have relationship, this way I will still get the course, but this is necessary to do in all function... I want a automatically way to dont be necessary add in ```index(Course $course)```,  ```show(Course $course)``` ,  ```update(Course $course)```